# Dense set difference of matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $1<p<N-1$ be a positive integer and $$S=\{\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}:\exists \lambda\in\mathbb{R}^p\backslash\{\mathbf{0}\}\quad \lambda_1\mathbf{I}+\lambda_2\mathbf{A}+,...,+\lambda_p\mathbf{A}^{p-1}=\mathbf{0}\}$$

I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}\backslash S$ is dense (in $\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$).

I'm aware that it has to do with the set of zeros of a polynomial, but don't know how to use this. In fact, $p$ can be even smaller than $N-1$ if necessary for the result.

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The set $\mathcal{R}^{N\times N}$ is the set of $N\times N$ matrices with real valued entries. You're right about the set difference, I changed it in the question. $\lambda$ is a $p$ dimensional real valued vector with entries $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_p$.

Comment: In fact, I think that I have figured it out. It follows because the set of matrices with N distinct eigenvalues is dense (and open), and has minimal polynomial equal to characteristic polynomial of degree N>p.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is a polynomial function of the entries of $A$, and is not identically $0$.  When the discriminant is nonzero, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial, and thus has degree $N$.